# Determine image type by file header

Tags: images, headers

I have a strange image (actually several) that I need to figure out the type of.  It opens correctly in the standard Windows photo viewer, but doesn't make any indication of the type.  I can rename the file to .jpg, .png, etc. and it will still open the same.

The first 3 bytes of the file are 'BMB' (**not** BMP, that isn't a typo) and then it's raw binary data that doesn't translate into readable characters.  Usually a tag like this is the file/image format/type.  Does anyone know what type of image this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic for Windows bitmap files is actually two bytes – `BM`, not `BMP`. The next four bytes are the size of the file itself, and the `B` is just a coincidence.

- Wikipedia: [BMP file format#Bitmap file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header)

Most Unixes, have a `file` command that can recognize many file formats using a database. For Windows, Cygwin and [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) come with this command.

Comment: Extra kudos for the link to the `file` command so I could verify it myself.  I feel a little silly for being confounded by a bitmap...